# before_filter rendering or redirect. Not calling create method after.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm calling a before_filter to authenticate my API via an auth_token before a user can create a friendship. The problem I have is the before_filter is successfully being called and it is is successfully authenticating the user however after running the before_filter it is not continuing and calling the create method.

Here is what returns when I POST to the create url.

```
Filter chain halted as :require_auth rendered or redirected
```

Here is my Friendship Controller create method:

class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :require_auth

  def create
    friendID = params[:friend_id]
    userID = currently_logged_in.id
    unless userID == friendID or Friendship.exists?(userID, friendID)
      transaction do
        create(:user_id => userID, :friend_id => friendID, :status => 'pending')
        create(:user_id => friendID, :friend_id => userID, :status => 'requested')
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the application controller where the before_filter runs :require_auth

```
  def require_auth
    auth_token = request.headers["HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    @user = User.find_by_auth_token(auth_token)
    if @user.auth_token
      render :status => 200, :json => {:message => "Authorization accepted"}
    else
      render :status => 401, :json => {:error => "Requires authorization"}
      return false
    end
  end
```

Any ideas whats going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your `require_auth` is your problem change it to the following(as you can see in railscasts episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api):

```
def require_auth

   authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
     user = User.find_by_auth_token(token)
   end

end
```

also move the before_filter into application controller if you need for the whole API if not put `require_auth` under protected method in `ApplicationController` and call it with before_filter from `FriendshipsController`